# Appending class to anchor based on page

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a navigation portion of my site and have the current page in the sidebar have the class "current" to change it's color. I'm using jQuery as if I'm not mistaken, addClass works in IE 8 and 9 whereas using javascript will require extra coding to get it to be cross browser compatible.

```
<div id="link_location">onandon</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var id = document.getElementById('link_location').innerHTML;
    $("'#"+ id +"'").addClass('current');
</script>

<div id="sidebar">
    <div id="links">
        <li><a id="allofnothinginstall" href="allofnothinginstall.html">All of Nothing</a></li>
        <li><a id="onandon" href="onandon.html">on and on</a></li>
    </div> 
</div>
```

I'm sure there are neater ways to do it, but I'm still learning javascript and don't know how to pull the url from the window location and only keep the page name. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: So you just want to get the page name from the current url? What is all this code about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run your JS within the document ready handler, so that the DOM will be loaded. And you should not have `'` characters in the selector.

```
$(function() {
    var id = $("#link_location").text();
    $("#" + id).addClass('current');
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still getting used to working on strings so the quotation marks sometimes mess me up and completely forgot about the document ready handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the path to your current page by sending `window.location.pathname`. For this page, that returns `"/questions/18246248/appending-class-to-anchor-based-on-page"`. You can either use a regex on that or .slice().

open up your console (in dev tools), type `window.location`, and hit enter. it'll show you all the information you have access to, including `window.location.pathname`